# How can someone check off a task without it checking off the task for everyone in Trello

Tags: trello

I am a student and my teachers really want to use Trello. I really like the setup and I think it's great. The only thing that is super super frustrating is that as the student, if I want to be able to check off assignments I have to copy them to my own boards. That involves a lot of craziness.

First I have to create another board for each class, then I have to copy the little cards, and then I have to move them to the proper boards. Is there a way for my teachers to assign these tasks/cards to multiple people and then track who has finished it and who hasn't?

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to do this directly through the user interface.  If you feel comfortable with some light scripting, you can automate the board creation and card copying by [using the Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/), but otherwise, your best bet is to [make a feature request](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).